# Change layout/style of Access Denied screen?

Tags: 2010

Is it possible to change the layout or style of the Access Denied screen to make the whole thing less scary and the "Request access" link stand out?

[image: Access Denied screen in Sharepoint]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you edit the existing Access Denied page it will affect all the web application sites in that server/farm. So better to create a custom simple page with your customization and make that custom page your "Access Denied" page for your web application.

Below are the steps involved:

1. Create custom Access Denied page and place it in layouts folder. (**C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS\1033**)
2. Run the below powershell command which will set that page as your web apps Access Denied page.

   $webApp = Get-SPWebApplication **YourWebAppURL**
   $webApp.UpdateMappedPage([Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPWebApplication+SPCustomPage]::AccessDenied,"/_layouts/1033/Custom_AccessDenied.html")

   $webApp.Update()

See this [article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/fabdulwahab/archive/2012/10/02/how-to-customize-error-page-page-not-found-and-access-denied-in-sharepoint-2010.aspx) for more details.